# Good ways to get teaching experience in non-teaching position

Tags: career-path, teaching, germany

I am a PhD student working full time at a research institute (Drittmittelstelle) in Germany. This is a pure research, non-teaching position. I did both my master and bachelor at a Fachhochschule (FH) (University of applied sciences) and I am contemplating trying to get a position as a professor at a Fachhochschule following my PhD.

The issue is, that to apply for a professor position you need to have teaching experience, which I don't get through my current position. Because everything else is perfect, I would not want to change to another PhD position (with teaching responsibilities). So my question is: what are good ways to get teaching experience (in Germany) that will have relevance for a later FH professorship without having to change to a teaching position? My group leaders want to support me in this, and would allow me to make time for teaching alongside my regular PhD and project work (and maybe lighten my regular work lot a bit), as long as I still get those done.

I did single lectures and smaller workshops before -- but I doubt that would count as enough of a teaching experience for an application. I also have inquired at my old alma mater, but as long as they have all teaching requirements covered by existing staff, they don't really want to or can't hire an outside person (me) to lecture.

Comment: "to apply for a professor position you need to have teaching experience,"  Are you sure?  I'm not sure about Germany but this is not normally true.

Comment: What discipline is this?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist as a student, I was part of an appointment panel (I am not sure how to translate, in German it is Berufungskommission) for a vacant professor position at my FH, and teaching experience was one of several requirements that applicants needed to have, and I know that this is true at most Unis as well. Discipline: side branch of engineering.

Comment: Are you talking about seeking a W3 position?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist This is about an FH ("university of applied sciences"), where not only teaching experience but also industry experience is generally expected.

Comment: Do you care about *giving lectures*, or just about *some* kind of teaching (like giving exercise classes)?

Answer (score 3):

For similar reasons I applied as a lecturer at a dual university (Duale Hochschule). The dual university also had lecturers who work in the cooperating business (and do not have a PhD), for example. Hence, they were also not hesitant to let me lecture a course although I also still am a PhD student.